# How to scrape text from html email by Python's Selenium lib

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

please can someone help me to extract some text from html email? Information it's within the nested table. I was trying to extract it by xpath also catch that parent table first by width, but without success:/
If selenium is stupid approach give me better direction please. I choose it coz I'm using in it later on for handling
some web on base of information which I'll extract in here.

Thank you.

This is one of the text(phone in this case) example which I need to get out of there:

608910536

Here is the example of email in html:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="cs" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <style type="text/css">
                    * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
                    BODY {font-family: Arial;color: black;margin: 5px 30px 30px 30px;}
                </style>
    <title>OctopusPro REPORT</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#717272" style="background:#717272;" xmlns="">
    <center>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="765" bgcolor="#717272" style="width:765px;margin: 0 auto;background:#717272;">
        <tr>
          <td style="border-top: 1px solid #808080; border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;">
            <center>
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8" border="0" width="740" style="width:740px;margin: 0 auto;">
                <tr>
                  <td width="205" style="width:205px;">
                    <a href="http://www.octopuspro.cz" target="_blank" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;">
                      <img src="cid:logo.png" alt="OctopusPro" title="OctopusPro" style="border:none;" />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td width="160" style="width:150px;"> </td>
                  <td width="350" align="left" style="width:350px;text-align:left;">
                    <span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;">
                      <a href="http://monitoring.octopuspro.cz/default.aspx" target="_blank" style="color: #c7c7c7; text-decoration: none;" alt="ON-LINE PŘIHLÁŠENÍ DO APLIKACE OCTOPUSPRO">
                        <span style="color: #f68a26;">»</span>  
                                                    <span style="text-decoration:none;">ON-LINE PŘIHLÁŠENÍ DO APLIKACE OCTOPUSPRO</span></a>
                      <br />
                      <a href="http://monitoring.octopuspro.cz/default.aspx" target="_blank" style="color: #c7c7c7; text-decoration: none;" alt="VYHLEDÁVÁNÍ INZERCE DLE TEL. ČÍSLA A EMAILU">
                        <span style="color: #f68a26;">»</span>  
                                                    <span style="text-decoration:none;">VYHLEDÁVÁNÍ INZERCE DLE TEL. ČÍSLA A EMAILU</span></a>
                      <br />
                      <a href="http://monitoring.octopuspro.cz/List.aspx?fulltext=true" target="_blank" style="color: #c7c7c7; text-decoration: none;" alt="VYHLEDÁVÁNÍ INZERCE V ARCHIVU">
                        <span style="color: #f68a26;">»</span>  
                                                    <span style="text-decoration:none;">VYHLEDÁVÁNÍ INZERCE V ARCHIVU</span></a>
                      <br />
                      <a target="_blank" style="color: #c7c7c7; text-decoration: none;" alt="HISTORIE ZPRACOVANÝCH INZERÁTŮ" href="http://monitoring.octopuspro.cz/MP_Main.aspx?processedadvert=1&amp;IdUser=48880&amp;DateFrom=25.5.2021&amp;DateTo=25.5.2021">
                        <span style="color: #f68a26;">»</span>   <span style="text-decoration:none;">HISTORIE ZPRACOVANÝCH INZERÁTŮ</span></a>
                      <br />
                      <a href="http://octopuspro.cz/mclient/Help.htm" target="_blank" style="color: #c7c7c7; text-decoration: none;" alt="NÁPOVĚDA PRO PRÁCI S WEBOVOU APLIKACÍ">
                        <span style="color: #f68a26;">»</span>  
                                                    <span style="text-decoration:none;">NÁPOVĚDA PRO PRÁCI S WEBOVOU APLIKACÍ</span></a>
                      <br />
                      <a href="http://octopuspro.cz/mclient/_VideoSkoleni.aspx" target="_blank" style="color: #c7c7c7; text-decoration: none;" alt="VIDEO NÁPOVĚDA">
                        <span style="color: #f68a26;">»</span>  
                                                    <span style="text-decoration:none;">VIDEO NÁPOVĚDA</span></a>
                    </span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;">
            <center>
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8" border="0" width="740" style="width:740px;margin: 0 auto;">
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="text-align:left;">
                    <span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;color:#c7c7c7;">
                                                Monitoring realit ze dne: <strong>25.05.2021</strong><br />Uživatel: <strong>Káňa Ondřej</strong>, Realitní společnostM&amp;M pobočka Brno 7</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="765" bgcolor="white" style="width:765px;margin: 0 auto;background: white;font-size:13px;">
        <tr>
          <td style="background:#fbcd31;" bgcolor="#fbcd31">
            <!-- HEADER -->
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8" border="0" width="765" style="width:765px;margin: 0 auto;font-size:14px;">
              <tr>
                <td width="130" style="width: 130px; padding: 4px 8px; text-align: center;" align="center" valign="middle">
                  <strong>     KRAJ     </strong>
                  <a id="header_navigation" name="header_navigation" style="text-decoration:none;"></a>
                </td>
                <td width="130" style="width: 130px; padding: 4px 8px; text-align: center;" align="center" valign="middle">
                  <strong>TRANSAKCE</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="220" style="width: 220px; padding: 4px 8px; text-align: center;" align="center" valign="middle">
                  <strong>KATEGORIE</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="120" style="width: 120px; padding: 4px 8px; text-align: center;" align="center" valign="middle">
                  <strong>NABÍDKA</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="120" style="width: 120px; padding: 4px 8px; text-align: center;" align="center" valign="middle">
                  <strong>POPTÁVKA</strong>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8" border="0" width="765" bgcolor="white" style="width:765px;margin: 0 auto;background: white;font-size:12px;text-align:left;">
        <tr>
          <td width="130" rowspan="1" bgcolor="#dddddd" align="center" valign="middle" style="width: 130px; padding: 0 8px; background: #dddddd; border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: center;">
            <strong>JIHOMORAVSKÝ</strong>
          </td>
          <td width="130" rowspan="1" bgcolor="#dddddd" align="center" valign="middle" style="width: 130px; padding: 0 8px; background: #dddddd; border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: center;">prodej</td>
          <td width="220" bgcolor="#dddddd" style="width: 220px; height: 30px; padding: 0 8px 0 30px; background: #dddddd; border: 1px solid #dddddd;">Pozemek</td>
          <td width="120" style="width: 120px; padding: 0 8px; background: #fbcd31; border: 1px solid #be780a; text-align: center;">
            <a href="#11/4/1/1" style="width: 127px; color: #6a4204; text-decoration:underline; text-align: center;">ZOBRAZIT</a>
          </td>
          <td width="120" style="width: 120px; padding: 0 8px; background: #fbcd31; border: 1px solid #be780a; text-align: center;">
            <span> </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="765" bgcolor="#717272" style="width:765px;margin: 0 auto;background:#717272;">
        <tr>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center>
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="765" bgcolor="white" style="width:765px;margin: 0 auto;background: white;font-size:13px;">
                <tr>
                  <td style="background:#fbcd31;" bgcolor="#fbcd31">
                    <!-- ZÁHLAVÍ OBLASTI (KRAJ) -->
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8" border="0" width="765" style="width:765px;margin: 0 auto;font-size:13px;">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="130" style="width: 130px; text-align: left;" align="left" valign="middle">
                          <strong style="display:block; padding: 4px;">
                                                        Kraj:
                                                        <span style="font-size: 130%;">JIHOMORAVSKÝ</span><a id="11/4/1/1" name="11/4/1/1" style="text-decoration:none;"></a></strong>
                        </td>
                        <td width="130" style="width: 130px; text-align: right;" align="right" valign="middle">
                          <strong style="display:block; padding: 4px;">
                            <a href="http://monitoring.octopuspro.cz/default.aspx" target="_blank" style="color: black; text-decoration: underline;">Otevřít on-line OctopusPro monitoring</a>
                          </strong>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="width:100%; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 13px; border-left: 1px solid #9b9a99; border-right: 1px solid #9b9a99;">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="95" bgcolor="#867bae" align="center" style="width: 95px; padding: 4px; background: #867bae; border: 1px solid #9b9a99; border-left: 1px solid #867bae; border-right: none; text-align: center;">
                          <strong style="color: white;">NABÍDKA</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" style="padding: 4px; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #9b9a99; border-right: none; border-left: none;">
                                            Okres: <strong style="font-size: 14px;">BRNO / POZEMEK</strong></td>
                        <td width="95" bgcolor="#6cc04b" align="center" style="width: 95px; padding: 4px; background: #6cc04b; border: 1px solid #9b9a99; border-right: 1px solid #6cc04b; border-left: none; text-align: center;">
                          <strong style="color: white;">PRODEJ</strong>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <!-- INZERÁT -->
                    <center>
                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" border="0" width="745" bgcolor="#dddddd" style="width:745px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #9b9a99; background: #dddddd; font-size: 12px; text-align: left;">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="60" align="center" valign="top" style="width: 60px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                            <strong style="color:#717272;font-size: 12px;">
                                                                    datum:
                                                                    </strong>
                          </td>
                          <td width="450" align="left" valign="top" style="width: 450px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                            <strong style="font-size: 15px;">Pozemek, Brno, 904 m2</strong>
                            <span style="color:#717272;"> (id:7175832)</span>
                          </td>
                          <td width="80" align="left" valign="top" style="width: 80px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                            <strong style="color:#717272;font-size: 12px;">
                                                                    cena:
                                                                    </strong>
                          </td>
                          <td width="75" align="left" valign="top" style="width: 75px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                            <strong style="color:#717272;font-size: 12px;">
                                                                    kontakt:
                                                                    </strong>
                          </td>
                          <td width="70" align="left" valign="top" style="width: 70px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                            <strong style="color:#717272;font-size: 12px;">
                                                                    opak. tel.:
                                                                    </strong>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">25.5.21</td>
                          <td align="left" width="400" valign="top" style="width: 400px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">Stavebni pozemek 904m2  
                                                                    <a target="_blank" href="https://reality.bazos.cz/inzerat/137022587/stavebni-pozemek-modrice.php" style="color: #ff0000; text-decoration: underline;">(zdroj)</a><br /><span></span></td>
                          <td align="left" valign="top" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; font-size: 13px;">
                            <strong>8 400 000 Kč</strong>
                          </td>
                          <td align="left" valign="top" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; font-size: 15px;">
                            <strong>
                              <span>
                                <span>608910536<br /></span>
                              </span>
                            </strong>
                          </td>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                            <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height:100%;width:100%;font-size: 12px;">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center;vertical-align:top;">
                                  <a target="_blank" style="color: #ff0000; text-decoration: underline;" href="http://monitoring.octopuspro.cz/List.aspx?phone=608910536">(5x)</a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="right" valign="bottom" style="text-align: right;vertical-align:bottom;">
                                  <br />
                                  <br />
                                  <a href="#header_navigation">zpět</a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="5" align="right">
                            <a style="color:blue;" href="http://monitor.octopuspro.cz/List.aspx?s=email&amp;idHitx=7175832" target="_blank">detail v aplikaci</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </center>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td> </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </center>
    <center>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="740" style="width:740px;margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div style="font-size: 9pt; color:black;">V případě jakýchkoliv dotazů a informací, prosím, kontaktujte oddělení péče o klienty<br /><br />
                                                (Mobil: +420 776 259 259, 
                                                E-mail: <a style="color: silver;" href="mailto:info@octopuspro.cz">info@octopuspro.cz</a>, 
                                                Web: <a style="color: silver;" href="http://www.octopuspro.cz">www.octopuspro.cz</a>)
                                            </div>
            <div style="font-size: 7pt; color:black;padding-top:10px;margin-top:10px; ">Právní informace: Tento e-mail .</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your HTML and it seems that there is only one specific url that comes with your number (http://monitoring.octopuspro.cz/List.aspx?phone=). A fast prototyping approach is to grep for this and its following numbers. I made a fast check on regex101 so you can check out there too and maybe play a little bit with until you understand it: https://regex101.com/r/hTpTdy/1
After you understand it, you have to use regex in your code and fetch the numbers (in this case its the \w from the regex) with your preferred regex library and you're done.

TLDR; for a fast solution and specific to this case use this regex http://monitoring.octopuspro.cz/List.aspx?phone=\w*

Comment: Hi, thank you for right direction. I was going on birds with cannon too much focus on selenium that I overlooked that. Simple regex solve it.                                   phone = re.search('phone', body_html)
phone_line = re.search('phone', body_html)
print(phone_line)
print(re.search('phone.+', body_html).group())